# filter document in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

We have a collection of employees:

```
// Sample document.
        Document emp2 = new Document();
        emp2.put("name", "Charlotte Neil");
        emp2.put("website", "webcodegeeks.com");

        Document emp2_addr = new Document();
        emp2_addr.put("addr_line1", "Fremont, AK");
        emp2_addr.put("zip_code", "19408");
        emp2.put("address", emp2_addr);
```

The below filter is not working:

```
AggregateIterable<Document> documents = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
                new Document("$match", Document.parse("{ \"name\": \"Charlotte.*\" }")) 
        ));
```

What is the correct syntax to filter the above?
Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex can be applied to a string field in the following ways:

```
1. new Document("$match", Document.parse("{ 'name':/Charlotte.*/ }"))
2. new Document("$match", Document.parse("{ 'name':{ $regex: 'Charlotte.*' } }"))
```

For more information on the regex, please check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

Comment: This works.However,what would be the equivalent for  Aggregates.match

Comment: @IUnknown Sorry, didn't get you. Both are equivalent for Aggregates.match. If you are using match method, it would go like this: ```Aggregates.match(Document.parse("{ 'name':/Charlotte.*/ }"));```